# Export Data Table To Excel

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, export-to-excel, excel-2013

I am having a formatting issue when exporting my data table to Excel.  The data is exported as it should, however if you look at my image, sometimes the cell height is increased and I am not sure why.  I want the data to look the same from row to row.  This is the syntax I am using to export

```
for (var i = 0; i < tbl.Columns.Count; i++)
workSheet.Cells[1, i + 1] = tbl.Columns[i].ColumnName;
for (var i = 0; i < tbl.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < tbl.Columns.Count; j++)
         workSheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = tbl.Rows[i][j];
}
```

And here is an image that shows my formatting issues that I want to find a way to overcome.  Can someone show me what syntax I need in order to have all row height/width the same?
[Issue Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x35O0.png)

EDIT
I tried this, but it throws an error and does not format as needed

The error is

> System.Exception

```
 Excel.Range range1 = workSheet.get_Range("A2", "S2000");
 range1.EntireRow.Height.Value = 15;
```

Comment: If I right click the cell and view properties after the .xlsx is generated, wrap text is checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are over complicating it.  Just use the `UsedRange` property.  If `workSheet` is your actual variable name and 15 is the actual height you want to set, the below will work:

```
workSheet.UsedRange.EntireRow.RowHeight = 15;
```